# Unique MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I really am struggling with a MySQL query, I have a table named 'info' and in it I have a column called 'rating' in it I have ratings between 1-10.

Now I need to generate a percentage value of how many ratings are from 1-6 and 7-8 and 9-10 but I need them to display desperately and after that I need a second query that can subtract the percentage value of the results from 1-6 and 9-10.

The query below is as close as I could get from all my research however I don't know how to get a percentage of ratings 1-6 only and not all of them and also how to get a second query to subtract the 1-6 and 9-10 rating percentages. Any help would be amazing.

```
SELECT rating, 
   COUNT(*) AS Count, 
   (COUNT(*) / _total ) * 100 AS Percentege 
FROM info, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS _total FROM info) AS myTotal 
GROUP BY rating
```

Comment: Sample data would really help your question...can you add some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select if(rating between 1 and 6, '1-6', 
          if( rating between 7 and 8, '7-8',
              '9-10' )
          ) as rating_range,
          count(1) as num
from info 
group by rating_range
```

[fiddle code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4dc5f/14)